# Pandas: Timestamp messed up after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the latest instance per each group using the following code. It does what I want, except for that the Timestamp gets converted to numpy.datetime and the date is subtracted by one day.
This doesn't seem like the correct behavior. Is this a bug or am I missing something.

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]: 

ticker currency date
0 AACE NaN NaT
1 AAP US Dollar 2012-12-29 00:00:00
2 AAP US Dollar 2013-04-20 00:00:00
3 AAP US Dollar 2013-07-13 00:00:00
4 ABBEY British Pound 2012-12-31 00:00:00
5 ABBEY British Pound 2013-03-30 00:00:00
6 ABBEY British Pound 2013-06-30 00:00:00
7 ABBNVX NaN NaT
8 ABBV US Dollar 2012-12-31 00:00:00
9 ABBV US Dollar 2013-03-31 00:00:00
10 ABBV US Dollar 2013-06-30 00:00:00


In [38]: df.date[3]
Out[38]: Timestamp('2013-07-13 00:00:00', tz=None)

In [39]: df.groupby('ticker').last()
Out[39]: 


currency date ticker

AACE NaN NaN
AAP US Dollar 2013-07-12T17:00:00.000000000-0700
ABBEY British Pound 2013-06-29T17:00:00.000000000-0700
ABBNVX NaN NaN
ABBV US Dollar 2013-06-29T17:00:00.000000000-0700


In [40]: df.groupby('ticker').last().date[1]
Out[40]: numpy.datetime64('2013-07-12T17:00:00.000000000-0700')

In [41]:
```

EDIT:

I don't have the original example, but here is another example replicating the same behavior.

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]: 


ticker currency date
3227 WWW US Dollar 2013-03-23 00:00:00
3228 WWW US Dollar 2012-12-29 00:00:00
3229 WWW US Dollar 2013-06-15 00:00:00
3230 WWW US Dollar 2013-09-07 00:00:00
3231 WYLE NaN NaT
3232 YALUNI NaN NaT
3233 YKBNK NaN NaT
3234 YZCOAL NaN NaT
3235 ZACHRY NaN NaT
3236 ZAYOGR US Dollar 2013-03-31 00:00:00
3237 ZAYOGR US Dollar 2013-06-30 00:00:00
3238 ZAYOGR US Dollar 2012-12-31 00:00:00
3239 ZINC US Dollar 2013-06-30 00:00:00
3240 ZINC US Dollar 2012-12-31 00:00:00
3241 ZINC US Dollar 2013-03-31 00:00:00


In [58]: df.dtypes
Out[58]: 
ticker              object
currency            object
date        datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [59]: df.tail(7).groupby('ticker').last()
Out[59]: 


    currency date
ticker
ZACHRY NaN NaN
ZAYOGR US Dollar 2012-12-30T16:00:00.000000000-0800
ZINC US Dollar 2013-03-30T17:00:00.000000000-0700


In [60]: df.tail(6).groupby('ticker').last()
Out[60]: 


    currency date
ticker
ZAYOGR US Dollar 2012-12-31 00:00:00
ZINC US Dollar 2013-03-31 00:00:00

In [61]:
```

It looks like the column with Timestamp gets messed up only when there is NaT preset.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like the right times, but they're UTC timestamps with the time zone offset (e.g., the `-0700` in `2013-07-12T17:00:00.00-0700`).

See below:

```
In [93]: x = np.datetime64('2013-07-12T17:00:00.000000000-0700')

In [94]: x
Out[94]: numpy.datetime64('2013-07-12T17:00:00.000000000-0700')

In [95]: pandas.Timestamp(x)
Out[95]: Timestamp('2013-07-13 00:00:00', tz=None)
```

Why they're being converted like that: I'm not sure. Might be a bug, but it should be simple enough to `apply` something keep it all straight.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you constructed your example. Pls show the actual frame and the dtypes. It is possible you are not using and object dtype (as it has a time zone attached), so it cannot be interpreted correctly.

```
In [10]: df = DataFrame(dict(
                 A = ['AACE','AAP','AAP','ABBEY','ABBEY'], 
                 B = ['20121229','20130420','20130723','20121231','20130330']))

In [11]: df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]: 
       A                   B
0   AACE 2012-12-29 00:00:00
1    AAP 2013-04-20 00:00:00
2    AAP 2013-07-23 00:00:00
3  ABBEY 2012-12-31 00:00:00
4  ABBEY 2013-03-30 00:00:00

In [13]: df.groupby('A').last()
Out[13]: 
                        B
A                        
AACE  2012-12-29 00:00:00
AAP   2013-07-23 00:00:00
ABBEY 2013-03-30 00:00:00

In [14]: df.groupby('A').last().dtypes
Out[14]: 
B    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: The data type is pandas.tslib.Timestamp. It works fine if I converted the Timestamp to datetime and then do groupby. But what's unclear is that why is the conversion necessary? I don't really see why the type has to be datetime instead of Timestampe for the groupby().last() to work. Thanks.

Comment: what I mean is can you show the df you are starting with, e.g. show df.head(), and df.dtypes, also print an element in the date column, e.g. df.ix[0,'date']. I think you are using a timestamp with a timezone which may not work correctly (it could be a bug)